# Extending Root Partition By Deleting Swap Partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

Currently, I am running low on space on my root partition (I need more space to execute the 20.04 update).

I have a 14.9 GB swap partition, and a half-filled home partition. I'm thinking I would delete the swap partition, extend my root partition into some, or all of the remaining space, then make a new swap partition by resizing my home partition.

This is currently what my partitions in GParted look like, with the first few partitions are for my Windows dual boot:

[image: partitions in GParted]

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll convert your partition-based swap, to a /swapfile. We'll delete the swap partition, and use that unallocated space to increase the / partition. You'll need to have a bootable Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to proceed.

**Edit /etc/fstab...**

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

and comment out this line:

```
UUID=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx none  swap       sw       0       0
```

Save the edit and quit the editor

**Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB**

Start `gparted`.

Do a `swapoff` on the /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition

`Delete` the /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition, as it won't be used any more

`Drag` the right side of the /dev/nvme0n1p5 partition all the way right

Click the `Apply` button

Quit `gparted`

Reboot

**Create a /swapfile...**

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm xxG RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other uncommented “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

**Note**: Use SPACES, not TABS

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

Comment: would it be advisable to, instead of creating a swapfile, create a new swap partition, by reducing the size of my home partition, and creating a swap partition at the end, with the unallocated space? I also had a question about the swapfile, does it reside in root?

Comment: @MatthewHa /swapfile (which does reside in root) vs swap partition is moot, as either will work. All current versions of Ubuntu use a /swapfile (when clean installed). Yes, you could still use a swap partition, but it would require a somewhat risky RESIZE **and** MOVE of your /home partition. My procedure, is faster, safer, and doesn't require you to reduce your /home.